# Android onFling method of SimpleOnGestureListener not olways called

Tags: android, layout, gesture, onfling

I need to use onFling method of SimpleOnGestureListener.

```
private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public GestureListener() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        //Do something...
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //Do something...                   
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        //Do something...                   
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {            
        //Do something...                   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {     
        //Do something...                   
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }
}
```

OnScroll method is always called!

OnFling is not always called. Do I have to implement something?

Comment: onFling is called when you perform a fling gesture, seems that you didnt do that

Answer (score 0):

onFling gesture is only triggered after a certain distance and velocity is reached. You can do your own measurement instead by implementing your own OnMotionEventListener

Comment: Thanks, but how I can get the right minimum velocity?

Comment: You have to decide for yourself what you think is reasonable, thats what GestureListener will be doing, although I've done this myself, it will vary depending on your needs

Comment: Can you accept this answer to close the question, or add another answer if there was more to add, thanks